# Firebase anonymous authentication lost on app upgrades

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is what I've come up with to handle auth in my Android app backed by anonymous authentication.

```
public class StartupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener = firebaseAuth -> {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                LoggedInActivity.newInstance(this);
            } else {
                IntroActivity.newInstance(this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

This `StartupActivity` is the one defined in my `AndroidManifest.xml` to be my app's main launcher Activity.

The pattern works well: at the end of `IntroActivity`, my code authenticates the user anonymously and sends them to the `LoggedInActivity`. Every launch after, the anonymous authentication persists through and the user goes straight to `LoggedInActivity`.

However, some users report losing their anonymous authentication and effectively losing their data since my other inner-app screens are driven off Firebase nodes that correspond to the user's UID.

This is pretty bad, but it only happens to a few users it seems. And only for anonymous auth - if it happened for email auth, it wouldn't even be a big deal, since users could log back in. But for anonymous, it's a pretty big issue. The user loses everything.

The issue could be tied to either Firebase SDK updates or app updates - that's when it seems to happen most / be reported most by my users.

Why is this happening? Is this a bad pattern for auth? I love the concept of using anonymous authentication to allow users to simply use your app without login, and I believe this is Firebase's intention as well. It's almost like I need to give them the option of backing their account with an actual login though, since this bug has such bad effects.

Comment: Hey Anthony. At first glance your code looks completely normal to me, and an example of how you're supposed to implement this. The anonymous UID should only get lost when: 1) you call `signOut`, 2) the user uninstalls the app. If it indeed gets lost on an upgrade that would be a regression/bug. It should be fairly easy to reproduce. Did you already try that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It doesn't happen to me but it's reported by my users, so I don't know exactly how I'd reproduce. I just released an update last night and got 2 reports this afternoon - feels like more than just a coincidence to me. I don't use `signOut` anywhere in my app.

Comment: Hey @AnthonyChuinard, I have exact same issue and I cannot find the problem/solution. More about my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650500/flutter-firebase-auth-anonymous-currentuser-returns-null/60713699#60713699. Did you manage to solve this issue? Any help would be welcome. Thanks and have a nice day. :)

Comment: @matox No, they asked me for logs and to reproduce this, it's really hard to do that when I have 10,000 users and it happens to 5-10 of them.

Comment: @AnthonyChuinard I see, thanks anyway for responding. If you find anything helpful, let me know. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe I was able to reproduce this issue myself.

After getting an angry mail from a user, I tested what would happen if I updated the app (raising the version code for good measure) and tried to open it while my device was offline. Turns out Firebase logs me out, as I believe it might consider the internal copy of the Database outdated and wipes it completely, so it's basically the equivalent of a reinstall with no credentials. This doesn't happen after updating and opening the app while online.

This would explain why this only happens to a very small percentage of users, as they need to be Anonymous users who update the app and then try to open it with no internet connection in their devices, which I don't think would happen often.

Comment: Did you come up with a good (=reliable) solution for handling these situations?

Answer (score 1):

The system was designed so that a user can start out in anonymous mode, in order to keep signup friction low.  But you can write code to [convert an anonymous account to a permanent account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account).  This is what you should do for users who would like to retain their privileges if they're willing to provide some sign-in credentials.

Anonynmous auth credentials can be lost if you sign them out, or the user clears the app storage, or the user uninstalls the app.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in so quick, I understand all of your points, but there are users who do not want to retain their privileges beyond that simple app install, and Firebase offers this neat feature. I'm willing to take the risk of uninstall and app storage clearing - that's on the user - but to me it's a whole different story to randomly lose the auth for a small % of users.

Comment: Agreed on that Anthony: their sign-in status should not get lost outside of the cases Doug and I highlighted. We'd need to know more about the users where this is happening to see what causes it.